# Why is this solution to Reverse Integer (Leet Code) O((log10(n))?

Tags: java, big-o, logarithm

The [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) in question asks to reverse a 32-bit signed integer. Here's the given solution in Java:

```
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int pop = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
            if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
            rev = rev * 10 + pop;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

​According to the solution's explanation, it's time complexity is O(log10(n)) because there are roughly log10(x) digits in x. Intuitively, there seems to be n-1 iterations of the while loop, where n is the number of digits. (I.E: a 7 digit number requires 6 iterations) However, the solution and given complexity implies that the n is the integer itself and not the number of digits. Can anyone help me gain an intuitive understanding of why the above solution is log10(n) ?

Comment: FYI, big O is base insensitive when it comes to logs. O(log10(n)) = O(log(n)/log(10)) = O(log(n)). Totally irrelevant to your question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Let's say the x = 123.

int rev = 0;

rev = rev * 10 + x % 10; // rev = 3,   1st iteration.

x = x/10;              // x = 12

rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;  // rev = 3 * 10 + 2 = 32,  2nd iteration

x = x/10;              // x = 1

rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;  // rev = 32 * 10 + 1 = 321, 3rd iteration.

x = 0 so the  loop terminates after 3 iterations for 3 digits.
```

The conditionals within the loop check to see if the reversed values would exceed what a 32 bit number could hold.

So it is `log10(n)` exactly for the reason you stated in your question.  The log of a number `n` to a given base is the `exponent` required to raise the `base` back to the number `n`. And the exponent is an approximation of the `number of digits` in the number.

Based on your comment, it could also have been stated that "For any number `n`, where `m` is the the `number of digits in n`, the time complexity is `O(m)`."

Comment: if the number of iterations is directly related to the number of digits, why can't we just say that it's O(n) where n is the number of digits and not the number itself?

Comment: You could.  But the big O notation was expressed in terms of the number, not the number of digits.  So to get the number of digits you need to take the Log of the number.

Answer (score 3):

If x is an integer, then floor(log10(x)) + 1 is equal to the number of digits in x.

Let log(10)x = some number y. Then 10^y = x.
For example,

```
log(10) 10 = 1   
log(10) 100 = 2  
log(10) 1000 = 3 
...
```

When x is not a perfect power of 10:

```
floor( log(213) ) = 2
```

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: And for the "O(log10(n))" versus "O(log10(n) - 1)", the "-1" term becomes insignificant as "n" gets large.

Comment: @Ella Agree. Examples other than perfect integral powers of 10 would have made your explanation even clearer. Eg, ```floor( log(213) ) = 2```

Answer (score 0):

The given reverse algorithm requires in the worst case log_10(x) iterations. In other words, if the given input x consists of k decimal digits, it requires k iterations. But stating that this algorithm is O(log_10(x)) is misleading. This is not logarithmic algorithm. If the input size is not intuitive (for example, testing whether given integer is a prime), we need to rigorously apply the correct definition of input size. In Big O analysis, the input size is defined as the number of characters it takes to write the input. Since we normally encode integers in binary digits, the input size of this algorithm n is approximately log_2 x. Therefore, x is roughly 2^n. The worst case complexity W(x) = log_10 (x) = log_10(2^n) = n log_10(2). Therefore, the big O of reverse algorithm is O(n).